# cURL function to retrieve JSON data in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I coded this function to retrieve JSON data from an API (which returns data in JSON format).

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url,$json=false){
    $ch = curl_init();
    $headers = array();
    if($json) {
        $headers[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
        $headers[] = 'X-HTTP-Method-Override: GET';
    }
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array($headers),
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 5,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 3,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)'
    );
    curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if($response === false) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return $response;
    }
}
```

If $response is in fact `===false`, does it mean that cURL could not connect to the URL? Or could it also be that the API itself returned nothing (but the connection was successful)?

How do I know if cURL connects properly to the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHP curl doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) says:

> Return Values
>
> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the
>   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on
>   success, FALSE on failure.

Check error using [curl_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)

Comment: but, what happens if the url itself is 0 bytes? e.g.: example.com/test.txt < curl connects successfully but returns nothing because it is 0 bytes, and that's ok. but i need to know when the connection itself fails.

Comment: return empty string: `''`, remember to use strict comparison ===

Comment: i'll do that by prechecking the error: if($response === false && curl_error($ch)) return false;

Answer (score 1):

If `$response === false` then curl failed.

It does not mean that curl succeeded but got no content.  Since you've turned on `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`, that means the response will be returned as a string.  So, no content should be indicated by `$response === ''`.

Where you would run into trouble is if you only had two equal signs rather than three.  With three, you're doing type checking, so the boolean `false` is not the same as an empty string.